# Dynamic Menu Links Pointing to Component

Tags: angular

I am using a simple two column layout for one of the sections of my site. The left column contains a menu that is dynamically generated and the right column is where I want the content from each link in the menu to populate when a user clicks on each link, but I am unsure what the actually [href] for each menu link should be to direct the content to the router-outlet, which is another component called LessonsComponent.

Here are the various components:

lessons-layout.component

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"><app-sidemenu></app-sidemenu></div> <!--left menu-->
  <div class="col"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div> <!--content goes here from LessonsComponent-->
</div>
```

sidemenu component html **This is where the link is**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h2>Current Videos</h2>
            <div class="row" *ngFor="let videos of videos">
              <div class="col" >
                  <div><a [href]='lessons/{{ videos.order }}'>{{ videos.title }}</a></div> <!--link is here 'videos.order'-->  
              </div>
            <!--end of row-->  
            </div>
        <!--end of col-->
        </div>
    <!--end of row-->
    </div>
<!-- /container -->
</div>
```

app-routing

```
    { 
      path: 'lessons', 
      component: LessonsLayoutComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'lessons/:id', component: LessonsComponent },
      ]
    },
```

Lessons Component html

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h2>Video Content</h2>
            <div class="row" *ngFor="let videos of videos">
              <div class="col" >
                  <!--<div class="row" style="text-align: center;"><a [href]='videos.order'>{{ videos.title }}</a></div>   -->
                  <div class="row">{{ videos.content }}</div>
              </div>
            <!--end of row-->  
            </div>
        <!--end of col-->
        </div>
    <!--end of row-->
    </div>
<!-- /container -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change your routing config to:

```
[
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'lessons',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: 'lessons', 
    component: LessonsLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':id', component: LessonsComponent },
    ]
  }
]
```

since `LessonsComponent` is a child of `LessonsLayoutComponent`, its path should be just `:id` (and not `lessons/:id`)

add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your `app.component.html`, which will render your `LessonsLayoutComponent`

I created a [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jjg56g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) to play with

also, use [`routerLink` directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) and not `href` in your `SideMenuComponent`:

```
<a [routerLink]="[video.order]">{{ video.title }}</a>
```